# Store paths of 1's and 0's from root to leaf of a tree (Huffman coding)

Tags: c, path, tree, traversal, huffman-code

I built a tree to be used for Huffman compression. I want to traverse this tree from root to leaf for all leaves. Along these traversals, I would like to store a 0 if the left path was taken and a 1 if the right path was taken. My code works for the leftmost leaf, but when it should store the path of its sibling, it only goes back to the parent node instead of the root node and then goes to the right and stores only a 1 instead of 01.

[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNbLJ.png)

```
132 void printArr(){
133   int i;
134   for(i=0; i<top; i++){
135     printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
136   }
137   printf("\n");
138 }
139 
140 void storeCode(Node *rootNode){
141   
142   if(rootNode->left){
143     arr[top] = 0;
144     top += 1;
145     storeCode(rootNode->left);
146   } 
147   if(rootNode->right){
148     arr[top] = 1;
149     top += 1;
150     storeCode(rootNode->right);
151   } 
152   if(isLeafNode(rootNode)){
153     arr[top] = rootNode->data;
154     top += 1;
155     return;
156   } 
157   
158 }
```

The result looks like this (the non 0 or 1 numbers are the characters):

0 0 103 1 111 1 0 0 115 1 32 1 0 0 101 1 104 1 0 112 1 114

The result should look like this:

0 0 103 0 1 111 1 0 0 115 1 0 1 32 1 1 0 0 101 1 1 0 1 104 1 1 1 0 112 1 1 1 1 114

How do I change my code so that the function traverses the tree from the root to a different leaf each time (until all leaves have been visited).

Comment: Please put the code directly into the question (as text). It's not good to have an external link (which may one day no longer be inaccessible) and it's doubly not good to link to an image (which can't be copied and pasted).

Comment: @kaylum: Actually having the code **in** the question is a requirement on SO.

Comment: @olaf Isn't that what I requested? Did I say that wrong? Or are you just agreeing/emphasizing that it is a requirement?

Comment: @kaylum: Sorry, wrong word highlighted. Adding the code in the question ist not an option ("Please ..."), but a **requirement**. "Shall", not "should".